# Copied value on lambda[=] blocked by another encapsulating lambda[&]

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

User wants to pass-by-copy but it is blocked by encapsulating library's `[&]`, here is [coliru MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aab316501ffc596) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
int main(){
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs;
    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        auto func=[&,n](){  //[=] for n
            std::cout<<""<<n;   // user's code
        };
        //v library (actually inside another utility function)
        funcs.push_back([&](){   //user's "n" is blocked ??
            //(some library-related code here)
            func();
        });
        //^ library
    }
    //v library
    for(int m=0;m<3;m++){
        funcs[m]();  
    }
}
```

It prints `222` instead of `012`.
Why, and how to work around it?
Note that the library can't know about `n`.

According to a related question ([c++ lambda capture by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636336/c-lambda-capture-by-value)), the value should be copied correctly.

Here is a more complex [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8868183abd3e54f) that does the same thing, but can depict better how I actually use it :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::vector<std::function<void()>> libraryStuff;
template<class F>void addToLibrary(F f){
    libraryStuff.push_back([&](){   //user's "n" is blocked ??
        //some code library related
        f();
    });
}
void libraryDoNow(){
    for(int m=0;m<libraryStuff.size();m++){
        libraryStuff[m]();  
    }
}
int main(){
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs;
    for(int n=0;n<3;n++){
        auto func=[&,n](){
            std::cout<<""<<n;   // user's code
        };
        addToLibrary(func);
    }
    libraryDoNow();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are capturing `func`by reference in `funcs.push_back([&](){..};`

This leads to a dangling reference, since `func` goes out of scope before it is later called in:

```
//v library
for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
    funcs[n]();
```

You need to capture the local variable `func` by value to get a copy of it (and it's contained `n`-value).